# Ordering query results by two dates

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by

I am attempting to order some data using two dates but for whatever reason I am not able to achieve the results I am expecting.

Consider the following dataset:

```
       DOS          |     CreatedOn
2018-09-14 08:15:00 | 2018-09-14 13:17:09
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-14 13:40:42
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 12:59:01
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:02:11
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:21:10
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 01:47:07
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:52:47
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:22:26
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:23:07
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:23:53
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:24:09
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:25:17
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:26:34
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:30:35
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 14:34:45
2018-09-18 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 14:43:13
```

I am trying to order the dataset so that it is in the following order:

```
       DOS          |     CreatedOn
2018-09-18 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 14:43:13
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:30:35
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:26:34
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:25:17
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:24:09
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:23:53
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:23:07
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:22:26  
2018-09-14 08:15:00 | 2018-09-14 13:17:09
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 14:34:45
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:52:47
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:21:10
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:02:11
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 12:59:01    
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 01:47:07
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-14 13:40:42
```

However, what I am getting back from my query results is this:

```
        DOS          |     CreatedOn
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 14:34:45
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:52:47
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:21:10
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 13:02:11
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 12:59:01
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 01:47:07
2018-09-04 09:15:00 | 2018-09-14 13:40:42
2018-09-14 08:15:00 | 2018-09-14 13:17:09
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:30:35
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:26:34
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:25:17
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:24:09
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:23:53
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:23:07
2018-09-18 08:30:00 | 2018-09-18 14:22:26
2018-09-18 09:15:00 | 2018-09-18 14:43:13
```

Here is my query:

```
Select V.DOS,V.CreatedOn from Visits As V where V.DOS between '2018-09-01 00:00:00' and '2018-09-19 00:00:00' Order by V.DOS, V.CreatedOn desc
```

Both of the fields are DateTime fields.  Not sure why I am not getting the right order.  When I remove either of the fields from the order list and leave only one in it then it sorts correctly.  But when I place them both into the order by list it is not ordering by the first column first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the desc after V.DOS in the order by clause. You need it after each date that you want in descending order. Currently it is sorting by ascending DOS, then descending CreatedOn

Comment: That was it.  Is this something specific to ordering with dates?  Have never had to do this with other types before.

Comment: by default each column gets order by ascending. If you want to sort on descending, need to specify for each column.

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering and sorting on outside column **v.dos** but not on the ServiceDate

Please check the columns!

also, add **desc** on each order by column

Comment: Oh, good catch.  I forgot to change it in the post.  The query I posted is a minimum verifiable example of the issue, in the full query the field is aliased as 'ServiceDate'.

Comment: which query engine are you using? (oracle, teradata, hive, etc..)

Comment: try Order by V.DOS desc, V.CreatedOn desc